# Trying to access first member(itself a volatile pointer) of struct pointer does not return the stored member pointer but the struct address

Tags: c, pointers, struct, avr-gcc

I am trying to implement some pointer substitution for some communication interface by passing on a pointer to a struct of pointers to some implementation. 
This is meant to run on an Atmega328p and is being compiled with avr-gcc.exe (AVR_8_bit_GNU_Toolchain_3.5.4_1709) 4.9.2, installed in/via msys2 64bit on Windows 10

Now, given the following struct

```
typedef struct{
    volatile uint8_t* baudrateRegister;
    volatile uint8_t* statusRegister;
    volatile uint8_t* controlRegister;
    volatile uint8_t* dataRegister;
}CommRegisters;
```

I create this as a file scope variable in my main file and fill it with the corresponding addresses (in this case `0xB9, 0xB8, 0xBC, 0xBB`) according to my datasheet.

```
CommRegisters myInterface = {&BAUDRATEREGISTER, &STATUSREGISTER, &CONTROLREGISTER, &DATAREGISTER};
```

myInterface itself gets stored in 0x100, for reference sake, consistently. 
When i try to access any of them from inside the main function it returns the corresponding and expected addresses.

I then pass that to my init function in a different .c file

```
CommRegisters* storedRegisters
void init(CommRegisters* registers, uint32_t clockspeed){
    storedRegisters = registers;
}
```

and when i try to access any of the members i.e. by printing it with printf still in that same init function with

```
printf("storedRegisters %p\n", storedRegisters);
printf("storedRegisters->baudrateRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->baudrateRegister);
printf("storedRegisters->statusRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->statusRegister);
printf("storedRegisters->controlRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->controlRegister);
printf("storedRegisters->dataRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->dataRegister);
```

I should be getting the following addresses printed `0x100, 0xB9, 0xB8, 0xBC, 0xBB`, the first one being the struct itself and then the content of each member, being addresses to my registers. Instead accessing `storedRegisters->baudrateRegister` does return `0x100`, the address to the struct itself, not the content of the member.
The output on my console is then

```
storedRegisters 0x100
storedRegisters->baudrateRegister 0x100
storedRegisters->statusRegister 0xb8
storedRegisters->controlRegister 0xbc
storedRegisters->dataRegister 0xbb
```

With this I cannot access the first member pointer of my struct pointer, but all others seem fine. If I were to swap the order of e.g. control and baudrate register in my struct then the controlregister is the one that returns 0x100. 
Am I missing something essential?

I am compiling this with the following options:

```
avr-gcc -O2 -g2 -gstabs -std=c99 -Wall -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -MMD -MP -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections <some files>
```

and link it with

```
avr-gcc -Wl,-Map,.map -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt -lm -mmcu=atmega328p <some files>
```

Edit: Typo fixed

Edit2: i call the init function with

```
init(&myInterface, 100000L);
```

Edit3: fixed mixed around console output

Edit4: Added the 3 relevant source files.

The main.c file

```
#include "CommInterface.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

//uart
#include "Debug_uart.h"
static FILE uart_str = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, uart_getchar, _FDEV_SETUP_RW);
void startUart(void){
    stdout = stdin = &uart_str;
    uart_init();
    printf("\n\n\n\n############################################\n");
}

#define BAUDRATEREGISTER TWBR
#define STATUSREGISTER TWSR
#define CONTROLREGISTER TWCR
#define DATAREGISTER TWDR
CommRegisters myInterface = {&BAUDRATEREGISTER, &STATUSREGISTER, &CONTROLREGISTER, &DATAREGISTER};

void integration_runBMETester(void){
    startUart();
    init(&myInterface, 100000L);
    DDRB = (1 << PB5);
    while(1){
        PORTB |= (1 << PB5);
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB &= ~(1 << PB5);
        _delay_ms(500)
    }
}

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    #ifdef INTEGRATION_BME680
    integration_runBMETester();
    #endif
}
```

The CommInterface.h file

```
#ifndef _COMM_INTERFACE_H
#define _COMM_INTERFACE_H

#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct{
    volatile uint8_t* baudrateRegister;
    volatile uint8_t* statusRegister;
    volatile uint8_t* controlRegister;
    volatile uint8_t* dataRegister;
}CommRegisters;

void init(CommRegisters* registers, uint32_t clockspeed);

#endif // _COMM_INTERFACE_H
```

The CommInterface.c file

```
#include "CommInterface.h"
#include "registerAbstraction.h"

CommRegisters* storedRegisters;
void init(CommRegisters* registers, uint32_t clockspeed){
    printf("init\n");
    storedRegisters = registers;

    printf("storedRegisters %p\n", storedRegisters);
    printf("storedRegisters->baudrateRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->baudrateRegister);
    printf("storedRegisters->statusRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->statusRegister);
    printf("storedRegisters->controlRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->controlRegister);
    printf("storedRegisters->dataRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->dataRegister);

    abstraction_setRegisterToValue(storedRegisters->statusRegister, 0);
    abstraction_setRegisterToValue(storedRegisters->baudrateRegister, ((F_CPU / clockspeed) - 16) / 2);
}
```

Comment: edited it accordingly

Comment: Your console output is not in the order of your printf statements. Please make triple sure the code you are running is the code you are posting. Otherwise it gets very diffucult to reason about it very fast.

Comment: Fixed it, I swapped around the order of printing it as well as the order of the members inside the struct to see if it makes any difference. Must have copied the wrong output. The behaviour however stayed the same as described.

Comment: You must take a debugger to see what is passed to printf. It smells a bit like alignment where two different C files have different alignment directives in use.

Comment: Please show the entire program.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I don't have a debugger at hand (should probably finally order one). What i don't understand, both files are compiled in the same way with exactly the same flags by myself. How would the aligment directive change in that case?

Comment: Added the source code.

Comment: This doesn't look like valid C source. For example the .h file won't compile because of a missing semicolon.

Comment: Fixed the missing semicolon. I can assure you that it compiled and ran. Formatting for stackoverflow when copy pasting it in can lead to some missing characters.

Comment: Do you execute the code you think? Maybe not

Comment: @P__J__ not really sure what you are going for? I did let this run on an Atmega328p dev board and read the results through a FTDI USB adapter. I omitted the UART code because it's just a means to read the code and has proven to work so far when I tried to read out the pointers in the main file.

Comment: I did clean the build folder and made sure that all changes were included into the compile process, recompiling everything anew.

Comment: What does &BAUDRATEREGISTER display when you try to print it?

Comment: It shows the Address actual address 0xB9. That is the same address as defined in the atmel provided io328p.h file

Comment: should I be worried that the dataregister is only 1 byte before the controlregister? 0xbb and 0xbc accordingly. This would mean that the date register is only 1 byte large?

Comment: Please, show the definition of `TWBR` (for example)

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse this, reputation too low to comment, so I'll just put my 2 cents here. 
If it's useless, feel free to downvote and so on.

I compiled and ran the code (adapted for the PC), and assuming the definitions of `TWBR` and the other 3 to be something like `(*(uint8_t *)(0xB9))` , the correct and expected values were printed when the `init()` function was called in main.
It's hard to figure out without a debugger what's going on at your side, and as I can not see any obvious C errors, at best I can make wild guesses.

if I were to make an assumption, based on what you said (" If I were to swap the order of e.g. control and baudrate register in my struct then the controlregister is the one that returns 0x100. Am I missing something essential?") I would attempt try to put the blame somewhere in the `printf()` statements in `init()`.
Would you please try to swap the order of just the printf() calls (e.g. print the data register member first)? And see if the first 2 calls print `0x100` again.

```
 printf("storedRegisters %p\n", storedRegisters);
    printf("storedRegisters->dataRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->dataRegister);
    printf("storedRegisters->baudrateRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->baudrateRegister);
    printf("storedRegisters->statusRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->statusRegister);
    printf("storedRegisters->controlRegister %p\n", storedRegisters->controlRegister);
```

I know it's rudimentary and a bit of caveman debugging, but: 
1. I do not have your system to look closer myself
2. You do not have a debugger
3. I see no obvious C errors in the code you posted

Comment: I did originally have the print statements in a different order. I noticed the problem because the status register was being set correctly with 0 but the baud rate register wasn't (made the communication fail). I read the content of the registers directly by dereferencing the addresses to see if the initialisation works but it always failed for the baud rate. If i swapped the baudrate register position inside the struct definition in the h file with the status register, the status register didn't initalise with 0. So it is not just a problem with printf afaik.

Comment: More guesswork: have you tried to print directly the `registers` parameter passed to the `init()` function? Nothing seems to be wrong with the code...